# Draw a path with dashed start and solid end

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

I want to draw a line or path with dashed line style at its begining and a solid line at the end, but in only one path (I mean, not drawing two path), something like :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (3,0) -- (1,0)[dashed] -- (0,0)[solid] ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not possible to change the style of a path mid-way like this.  There are ways to simulate it, though, by breaking the path into two (in such a way that you could still write something similar to the above).  Would one of those be acceptable?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: You mean it can work using `\draw [dashed] (3,0) -- (1,0) ; \draw (1,0) -- (0,0)[solid] ;` ? Yes, but the junction of the lines is not as clean as if the line is define in one command (the first dash is closer to the solid line than to the second dash). This is the reason why I ask for a complete command... But maybe there is other ways that can solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe one could define the dash pattern carefully to get the join right.  It would depend on exactly what join you wanted to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you use two separate commands (`\draw (0,0) -- (1,0);\draw[dashed](1,0) -- (2,0);`) The first dashed part is connected to the solid line. What is it you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Sigmun Sorry I don't read correctly the question. I saw `line` instead of `path` also my answer is not really appropriated to your question. It's possible to begin the dash line with `pos=...` but it's very complicated  Then the junction of the lines will be  not very clean and it's what you want. If you want a good junction you can draw like this :`\draw [dashed] (1,0) -- (3,0) ; \draw (1,0) -- (0,-1)[solid] ;` You need to draw from the corner. The problem with the dash pattern is complicated.

Comment: @RoelofSpijker: you right, I can't see the problem at the junction anymore... There is some days like that !

Comment: Just an idea: If lines are longer then the spaces (or as same length), then you could shift the beginning of the line forward in first dash until the end reaches next dash. Implementation? I don't know... I only started learning TikZ. Most probably this is an idea for TikZ developers not for users.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If those are to be straight line segments, it couldn't get any simpler. It gets interesting with curves. Enclosed are a few examples, and I agree - it's too complicated. Clipping is the most accurate way to tell where the solid part should stop, but it requires its own scope. Fading is good for smooth transition but probably would only give headache if the path doesn't run more or less in one direction.
[image]

I'm quite sure there is a way to have a procedural stroke of the path, but I haven't found any information about that so far. I would personally enjoy a simple style that allows to easily morph the line type from start until end of a path, doing something similar to the second custom dash pattern but without all the typing. But for now, this is what I did:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.5pt]


\node at (200pt,40pt) [label=right:{2 line segments}]{};
% for straight segments this is the easiest:
%
\draw[dashed] (200pt,40pt) -- (60pt,40pt);
\draw (60pt,40pt) -- (0pt,40pt);


\node at (200pt,10pt) [label=right:{custom dash pattern}]{};
% for curves you can specify custom dash pattern, but it's cumbersome 
% having to specify every singly dash untill the line becomes solid:
%
\draw[dash pattern=on 10pt off 10pt on 10pt off 10pt on 10pt off 10pt on 10pt off 10pt on 10pt off 10pt on 10pt off 10pt on 10pt off 10pt on 100pt] (200pt,10pt) .. controls (40pt,40pt)  and (90pt,-30pt) .. (0,20pt);


\node at (200pt,-10pt) [label=right:{custom dash pattern}]{};
% it does however allow for nice density modifications (but also by hand):
%
\draw[dash pattern=on 10pt off 9pt on 9pt off 8pt on 8pt off 7.3pt on 7.3pt off 6.7pt on 6.7pt off 6.3pt on 6.3pt off 5.9pt on 5.9pt off 5.4pt on 5.4pt off 5.0pt on 5.0pt off 4.0pt on 4.5pt off 3.0pt on 4.0pt off 2.4pt on 3.5pt off 1.8pt on 100pt] (200pt,-10pt) .. controls (40pt,20pt)  and (90pt,-50pt) .. (0,0pt);


\node at (200pt,-30pt) [label=right:{2 curves: dashed $+$ clipped solid}]{};
% now there's 2 paths - a long dashed one and a clipped solid one:
%
\begin{scope}
\clip (-5pt,-70pt) rectangle (60pt,5pt);
\draw (200pt,-30pt) .. controls (40pt,0pt)  and (90pt,-70pt) .. (0,-20pt);
\end{scope}
\draw[dashed] (200pt,-30pt) .. controls (40pt,0pt)  and (90pt,-70pt) .. (0,-20pt);


\node at (200pt,-50pt) [label=right:{2 curves: dashed $+$ faded solid}]{};
% for a gradient toning down of the solid line you can use fading:
%
\draw[path fading=east] (200pt,-50pt) .. controls (40pt,-20pt) and (90pt,-90pt) .. (0,-40pt);
\draw[dashed,path fading=west] (200pt,-50pt) .. controls (40pt,-20pt) and (90pt,-90pt) .. (0,-40pt);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The clipped solid solution doesn't allow a nice junction between solid and dashed lines: the tail of the solid line is clip vertically due to the clip command. I also improve a bit the faded solution by fading also the dashed line in the other way.

Comment: Good idea with also fading out the dashed curve. Now the left part looks smoother. As for clip, a shape different than the orthogonal rectangle would naturally give better results.

Comment: You right, rectangle could be something else but this becomes hard to setup automagically !

Answer (score 4):

Another way (partially automated and gives you control over the amount of dashes):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={>=latex}]

% Normal dashed line
\draw[thick,black] (0,1) -- (1,1);
\draw[->,thick,black,dashed] (1,1) -- (4,1) node[anchor=west] {Normal dashed line};

% Specify dashed line starting coordinate and length
\draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\def\x{1}; \def\y{0}; \def\length{3} \def\N{4}; 
% Draw dashed line using normal lines
\pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{(0.5+1/(4*\N))*\length/\N}; \pgfmathparse{\N-1};
\foreach \i in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {\draw[thick,black] (\x+2*\i*\step,\y) -- (\x+2*\i*\step+\step,\y);}; 
\draw[->,thick,black] (\x+\length,\y) -- (\x+\length+0.01,\y) node[anchor=west] {Custom dashed line};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This simply mimicks a normal dashed line by drawing multiple lines after each other. Parameters are `\x` for the starting x-coordinate, `\y` for the y-level of the line, `\length` for the length in coordinates of the line and `\N` for the amount of stripes.

[image: arrows]