# Arrow half straight line half dotted

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw a path with dashed start and solid end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44737/draw-a-path-with-dashed-start-and-solid-end)

Can anyone help me figure out how to draw an arrow that is half straight line and half dotted? Much appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  It would be helpful if you showed what you tried so far, as it would then be clearer how you want to specify this. Do you mean something like `\draw [dotted] (0,0) -- (1,0); \draw [->] (1,0) -- ++(1,0);`?

Comment: @PeterGrill The tags already suggest TikZ but it's not clear Andreea is using the package.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: My question was more about the desired syntax to specify the path. Using two separate `\draw` commands is pretty simple as per my comment, but don't know if it was desired to specify it as one path.

Comment: @PeterGrill I understand but the questions doesn't mention Tikz. Your note would be clearer if it mentioned TikZ.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Ahhh!!! I forget that not everyone uses TikZ. :-), and that there are other options.

Comment: If you are using TikZ, please take a look at the question I've just linked to as I think it should solve your problem.  If not, please edit your question to explain what's different about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The link you posted had the answer to my question. Thanks a lot!