# How to draw the following image in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

How to draw the following image in TikZ? I can split it into 3 parts and then draw it, but is there any direct trick just by drawing two objects?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This draws it as two objects.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (90:0.2) arc(90:430:0.5 and 0.2);
    \draw[dash pattern=on 7pt off 3pt on 20pt] (-110:0.5) -- ++ (70:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are bothered by having to tune the dash pattern, but are fine with overpainting things in white, you can use this.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-110:0.5) -- ++ (70:1);
    \draw[preaction={draw,white,line width=4pt}] (90:0.2) arc(90:430:0.5 and 0.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Still 2 objects.

Comment: Is it possible to use `on` and `off` more (3 or 4 or any) times?

Comment: @C.F.G Yes, you can.

Comment: (sorry for questions on comment) And Is it possible to use this trick for `dashing` a part of  given curve? If the answer is different let me post a new question!

Comment: @C.F.G It depends on what you mean by "part of a curve". AFAIK you can add arbitrary sequences of `on` and `off`. Whenever you stop and restart the path, the dash pattern starts from scratch. You can also find out the length of a path with `decorations.markings`. But I may not fully understand the question.

Comment: part of a curve : e.g. --------- - - - ----- - - - - - - - - ----

Comment: @CFG Something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44898)? You can write a style that creates a dash pattern if there are rules. (Will decouple now but be back in a couple of hours.)

Answer (score 6):

You can draw it with a *single* path !

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand\singlepath[2]{% #1: a, #2: b (radii of ellipse)
  ++(70:#1 and #2) arc(70:-270:#1 and #2)
  ++(-90:#1 and #2) -- ++(80:2*#1 and 2*#2)
  ++(-100:3.3*#1 and 3.3*#2) -- ++(-100:2*#1 and 2*#2);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0)   \singlepath{1}{.3};
  \draw[red]            (2.5,0) \singlepath{1}{.2};
  \draw[dashed,blue]    (4.5,0) \singlepath{.5}{.3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]